# How to add multiple destinations for a java application in cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry, s4sdk

I developed a Java application using S4Hana SDK. After deploying the application to SAP Cloud platform, I set the destinations as an environment variable with below command.

`cf set-env firstapp destinations '[{name: "ErpQueryEndpoint", url: "https://URL", username: "USER", password: "PASSWORD"}]'`

Now, I would like to add a second destination for the same application. Can someone please help me?

Thanks,
Sankeerth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define multiple destinations in the environment variable. It is a JSON array.

```
cf set-env firstapp destinations '[{name: "ErpQueryEndpoint", url: "https://URL", username: "USER", password: "PASSWORD"},{name: "ErpQueryEndpoint2", url: "https://URL", username: "USER", password: "PASSWORD"}]'
```

In the execute method in the virtual data model you can define which destination to use:

```
BusinessPartnerService service = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService();

final List<BusinessPartner> businessPartners =
        service.getAllBusinessPartner().execute(new ErpConfigContext("ErpQueryEndpoint2"));
```

However, better than using the environment variables is to use the destination service.

Step 4 of the SDK tutorials explains how to use this service:
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-4-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-calling-an-odata-service/

With that it is even possible to have destination configurations per tenant.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solution helps me. I wonder if we can set these destinations in subaccount level rather than setting destinations for each application. In Neo environment, I am able to set the destinations in subaccount level. But Can we do the same way in cloud foundry?

Comment: Using the destination service, you can set the destinations on subaccount account level and on destination service instance level (e.g. per space).