# Unable to run the Java app in local environment

Tags: s4sdk

After developing a Java application, I ran the command

> mvn clean install

the build resulted in SUCCESS. Now, I tried to run the app in the local environment with the command

> mvn scp:clean scp:push -pl application

It resulted in the error as below.

> No plugin found for prefix 'scp' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Can someone please help me?

Thanks,
Sankeerth

Comment: Did you generate your project using the sdk archetypes?
Can you confirm that your pom file (application) lists the scp-neo-maven-plugin?

Comment: Yes, I generated the project using the SDK archetype for Cloud foundry with below command.   `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-tomee -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST`

Comment: Do we have any plugin for deployment to the local runtime of SAP Cloud Platform cloud foundry environment?

Comment: For the Cloud Foundry environment, the archetypes use `mvn jetty:run` for the `scp-cf-tomcat` archetype, `mvn tomee:run` for the `scp-cf-tomee` archetype, and `mvn spring-boot:run` for the `scp-cf-spring` archetype.

Comment: If the provided answer was helpful would you mind accepting it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scp:push is the command to deploy an application locally which is built for the neo environment as described [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-2-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-helloworld-on-scp-classic/).
It is required that you generated your project with a neo archetype, such as scp-neo-javaee7.

On Cloud Foundry for the tomee archetype you should be able to execute the following command to start the application locally:

`cd application
mvn tomee:run`

Additional information can be found in the [Tutorial for Cloud Foundry](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/19/step-3-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-helloworld-on-scp-cloudfoundry/)

Comment: The command depends on the archetype. You can use `mvn jetty:run` for the `scp-cf-tomcat` archetype, `mvn tomee:run` for the `scp-cf-tomee` archetype, and `mvn spring-boot:run` for the `scp-cf-spring` archetype.

Comment: mvn tomee:run is working, but it didn't give me an option to provide "ErpQueryEndpoint" details. So, I added the destination as an environment variable in manifest.yml file. But when I run the application it gave an error as below. **HTTP Status 500 - com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to retrieve destinations from environment variable "destinations". Have you defined this variable?**

Comment: Locally, you can set destinations simply via environment variables like on CF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49636397/how-to-add-multiple-destinations-for-a-java-application-in-cloud-foundry. Use your OS-specific command to set environment variables (Linux: export, Windows: set).